# VSCode Go to Definition doesn't work for aliased package installed with yarn in a monorepo

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, dependencies, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

In Visual Studio Code, for my JavaScript Node.js project, I expect to be able to put my cursor on a *require* line (see first code example below) and choose *Go to Definition* (typically F12), and it should open the file containing the definition of the module (or function) within a sibling package in my monorepo.

But lately I've been using corepack and yarn 4.1.0, `yarn install` and [workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).  This uses the [Plug'n'Play mechanism of yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp) and modules are not stored in a `node_modules` folder.  As a consequence, it seems that vscode can't locate the files and *Go to Definition* won't find the definition.

somewhere in ~/monorepo/main/something.js:

```
const foo = require('@modules/my_monorepo_module');
```

I expect to be able to go to the definition of `my_monorepo_module` or of `foo` above. But this doesn't work. It shows errors like:

> No definition found for foo
> No definition found for my_monorepo_module

My main `package.json` contains a reference to another package located within my monorepo though.  e.g.: a file layout like:

```
~/monorepo/main
~/monorepo/main/package.json
~/monorepo/modules/my_monorepo_module
~/monorepo/modules/my_monorepo_module/package.json
```

The main package depends on the local monorepo package with an alias beginning with `@modules/` to avoid name collisions with npm packages of similar names.  And it makes use of workspaces for everything in the `modules` folder of the monorepo.

~/monorepo/main/package.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@modules/my_monorepo_module": "../modules/my_monorepo_module"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "../modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Note that *Go to Definition* generally works on typical symbols and local *required* files just fine.  I suspect this problem has something to do with the way yarn resolves the files vs. the way vscode expects to locate them.

How can I make *Go to Definition* work in this yarn-monorepo scenario?

Comment: This also prevents copilot from discovering details about dependencies.